# Using ggpredict with model containing fixed effects

Tags: r, ggplot2, prediction

I am trying to plot the predicted values of a model containing interaction effects using ggplot in R. I have come pretty far, however, the issue arises when introducing fixed effects (I have a panel set covering country-years) in the model.

To generate the predictions I use `object<- ggpredict(model, terms = c("IV","Interaction"),vcov.fun = "vcovHAC", ci.lvl = .95)` However, this returns the error:

> Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) :  factor as.factor(FE) has new level 1.

I am assuming this occurs because the model automatically removes one level (of the fixed effects) to avoid perfect collinearity. Thus, there is a mismatch between the FE variable in the model and in the data.

My question is, how can I work around this so I can use ggpredict on the model with FE?

A reproducible sample using iris:

When using fixed effects in the model, the error occurs

```
> data(iris)
> 
> mod1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~  Sepal.Width + Petal.Width +
+            as.factor(Species), data = iris)
> 
> object <- ggpredict(mod1, terms = c("Sepal.Width"),vcov.fun = "vcovHAC", ci.lvl = .95)
Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor as.factor(Species) has new level 1
```

When excluding the fixed effects, ggpredic works nicely

```
> data(iris)
> 
> mod <- lm(Sepal.Length ~  Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, data = iris)
> 
> object <- ggpredict(mod, terms = c("Sepal.Width"),vcov.fun = "vcovHAC", ci.lvl = .95)
```

Comment: When I run your code, there is no error? Maybe try with a clean environment?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Did you run the code with as.factor(Species)? I still receive the error when using a clean environment only loading the ggeffects package.